# Correct use of semicolon

Tags: grammaticality

Can someone tell me if I should keep these semicolons as my teacher suggested, or revert to commas as I had originally?

-This is where I went wrong; I forgot the

-This realization doesn’t just apply to staying hydrated; this same mentality helps me

Thanks

Comment: So you don't believe your teacher, but you'll believe strangers on the internet??  (Yes, those are better as semicolons than as commas.)

Comment: I'd certainly prefer a dash in the first example, and probably a full stop in the second. But not commas.

Answer (score 1):

A comma is incorrect for both these cases without adding or re-ordering words, as they both involve two independent clauses without a conjunction. A detailed reference: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp

Semi-colons definitely acceptable here, but so are several other options depending on the tone you are aiming for.

Semi-colon alternatives:

- This is where I went wrong: I forgot the [...]
- This is where I went wrong. I forgot the [...]
- Not only does this realization apply to staying hydrated, the same mentality [...]
- This realization doesn’t just apply to staying hydrated—this same mentality helps me

In the first example, the colon is used to introduce an item: what went wrong. I think this is the best option for your first sentence.

The second example may or may not work, depending on your context and tone. You can use a period for more of a dramatic pause in a storytelling context, such as "I began my trek to work that day by taking the express bus instead of my usual train. This is where I went wrong. I forgot the construction on 3rd street..."

In my third example, I've reworded the first phrase such that it is a dependent clause rather than an independent one.

In the fourth example, I've substituted an [em dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html), which may be too informal or even incorrect, depending again on the intended tone and surrounding text. Em dashes help emphasize the conclusion of a sentence and are more casual than semi-colons or colons.